# Drop rows in pandas dataframe based on multiple conditions (one is regex)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following pandas dataframe called df:

```
   value1    value2   value3...........
0  ATG CX A  setB     ...
1  CTG CX B  setB     ...
2  AAG       setA     ...
3  AAG       setB
4  CTG       setA
5  CTG CX C  setB
6  GGG       setA
7  ATG       setA
8  AAG CX A  setB
9  GGG       setB
10 A7T       setB
```

I wish to drop the columns in which drop the rows in which `value1` contains strings that end with `CX` followed by a random letter.

Then if the same `value1` is in `setA` and `setB`, I want to keep `setA` and drop `setB`.

I want my end dataframe to look like this.

```
   value1    value2   value3...........
2  AAG       setA     ...
4  CTG       setA
6  GGG       setA
7  ATG       setA
10 A7T       setB
```

So I tried the following command:

```
df = df.drop(df['value1'].str.contains(r'\sPR\s.+$'))
```

but I get an error with many `nan`,

```
KeyError: '[nan nan nan na...........................]' not found in axis
```

Then I tried:

```
df = df[:, df['value1'].str.contains(r'\sPR\s.+$')]

df = df.drop_duplicates(subset='value1', keep='first')
```

but I get

```
ValueError: Location based indexing can only have [labels (MUST BE IN THE INDEX), slices of labels (BOTH endpoints included! Can be slices of integers if the index is integers), listlike of labels, boolean] types
```

Why am I getting this error? How do I achieve what I want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I constructed a toy dataframe like this:

```
d = {"value1": ["ATG CX A", "CTG CX B", "AAG", "AAG", "CTG", "CTG CX C", "GGG", "ATG", "AAG CX A", "GGG", "A7T"],
"value2": ["B", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

print(df)
      value1 value2
0   ATG CX A      B
1   CTG CX B      B
2        AAG      A
3        AAG      B
4        CTG      A
5   CTG CX C      B
6        GGG      A
7        ATG      A
8   AAG CX A      B
9        GGG      B
10       A7T      B
```

I then used the `.loc` operator while negating the str.contains() portion, like:

```
df = df.loc[~df['value1'].str.contains(r'\sCX\s.+$'),:]

print(df)
   value1 value2
2     AAG      A
3     AAG      B
4     CTG      A
6     GGG      A
7     ATG      A
9     GGG      B
10    A7T      B
```

Comment: I get this error `TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'float'`

Comment: I'm not sure why you are getting float from the `df['value1'].str.contains(r'\sPR\s.+$')` operation. This should yield boolean, in which case the `~` operator reverses the values. Try: `print(df['value1'].str.contains(r'\sPR\s.+$').dtype)`. You should get `dtype('bool')`.

Comment: I don't get it either, I tried this command before as well and it didn't work, the column is all strings

Comment: Is the output of `df['value1'].str.contains(r'\sPR\s.+$')` a float?

Comment: this is the output ```0        False
1        False
2        False
3        False
4        False
         ...  
45490    False
45491    False
45492    False
45493    False
45494    False
Name: value1, Length: 45495, dtype: object```

Comment: I think im not supposed to use the `~`

Comment: I added some additional details to this proposed solution, to show what I did. Hopefully this can help us understand what is different between your dataset and the one that I am using. What is the output of `df['value1'].str.contains(r'\sCX\s.+$').dtype`?

Comment: I figured it out I had to add an `na=False`